# Dynamic DropDownList works but how to get value? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

Hi I have the following code:

```
$dropdown = "<select name='test'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
echo $dropdown;


<form name="input" action="databaseupdate.php" method="post">
Select the car you want to edit and fill in the form, followed by clicking the update button.
<br>
Carname: <input type="text" name="nameupdate">
Year build: <input type="text" name="yearupdate">
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

And this one (databaseupdate.php):

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$db_name = "examples"; 
$tbl_name = "cars"; 


mysql_connect("$hostname", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$nameupdate = $_POST['nameupdate'];
$yearupdate = $_POST['yearupdate'];
$test = $_POST['test'];

$query = "UPDATE cars SET name = '$nameupdate', year = '$yearupdate' WHERE id='$test'"; 
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 


if($query){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='databaseconnect.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

So, the list is populated by all the car names from the database, which is good but from this point I don't know how to get the id that comes with the car's name.

I have tried it with a query that says "wher id='$test'" (as you can see in my code) but that returns empty.

Example of what I want:

If I select "Mercedes" from the dropdownlist and want to update it with the textboxes I want my code to know that Mercedes has an ID of 1.

I don't know how I can do that and I hope someone can help me out here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please include that dropdown inside the form??

Answer (score 0):

do like this: (just add dropdown inside your form)

```
<?php
    $dropdown = "<select name='test'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";
?>

    <form name="input" action="databaseupdate.php" method="post">
    Select the car you want to edit and fill in the form, followed by clicking the update button.
    <br>
    <?php echo $dropdown; ?>
    Carname: <input type="text" name="nameupdate">
    Year build: <input type="text" name="yearupdate">
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
```

Comment: It says Successful but it returns the name of the car and not the id that comes with it. And because there are no cars with an id of the cars name nothing will be updated.

Comment: That is because you have given name in option value.updated my code to have id after submit.

Comment: I have selected * from the database but it says the ID is undefined, however, it sees all the id rows (for each car there is an id that is undefined), any idea how to fix that?

Comment: can you share table structure and query, so that error can be detected quickly

Comment: The table cars has id, name and year    $query = "SELECT * FROM cars";

Comment: I have found out what I did wrong, instead of telling it to get id I said ID (capital letters), it works now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all include your dropdown inside the form.

Second if you want ID for your drop down selection, fetch id from db for the car name in `$result`, then do like this:

```
$dropdown = "<select name='test'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['ID']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
}
$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

<form name="input" action="databaseupdate.php" method="post">
Select the car you want to edit and fill in the form, followed by clicking the update button.
 <br>
echo $dropdown;
Carname: <input type="text" name="nameupdate">
Year build: <input type="text" name="yearupdate">
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="input" action="databaseupdate.php" method="post">
Select the car you want to edit and fill in the form, followed by clicking the update     button.
<br>
Carname: <input type="text" name="nameupdate">
Year build: <input type="text" name="yearupdate">
<select name='test'>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "\r\n<option value='{$row['name']}'>{$row['name']}</option>";
}?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

in your **databaseupdate.php**

```
$values = $_POST['test'];
```

$values contains selected values

The main problem is that you didn't included your select into form tag. Also to get values from POST method you should use **$_POST** in PHP or **$_REQUEST**

to check what $_POST contains you can use function

```
var_dump($_POST);
```